# Can electronic devices be installed on the pillar of UHV towers such as 345kV?

Tags: signal, power-engineering, energy-harvesting, electric-field

Can electronic devices be installed on the pillar of UHV towers such as 345 kV? Because I have an idea to install a remote automatic control electronic device on the tower to control the rotation and extension of the water pipe.

I know there must be a magnetic field problem because of the transmission line, I would like to ask if a signal is transmitted from the ground to this electronic device, which is located at a height of 60 meters, will the signal be seriously disturbed by the electromagnetic field?

Also is there any energy harvesting application in this situation? Because I want to use this technology to solve the power problem of this electronic device.

I am not good in this field, but I can survey some paper about this, so if you have any answer or reference, please tell me. You can just provide the reference rather than explaining it to me.

Comment: 345 kV - water pipe? Are you working for the owner of the pylons? Why is there a water pipe on a HV pylon?

Comment: to clean the insulator, we need water,so we also need the water pipe.

Comment: _” 345 kV”_ and _”I am not good in this field”_ Sounds like a recipe for disaster. Are you working for the grid owner?

Comment: Sure, you *can*. Fiber-optics (they're not as fancy as you think) may help for the signal isolation.

Comment: And I am also curious why you have to ask this question. You can't just climb up a 345kV tower and install stuff (well you can, but you might be dead, or worse, *expelled*), is this for like a brainstorming session in a class, or did they hire you to design something, or what?

Comment: well I am a worker ,and we climb the pylon of 345kV tower,we won't touch that transmission line,so just relax ,we won't die.

Comment: @winny my working is inspection and repairing of the  power transmission

Comment: oh and turn of the power of that transmission line

Comment: Okay, well yes it's possible to get a signal up the tower, and yes it's possible to harvest energy from the fields around high-voltage power lines, maybe even enough to drive a motor. Magnetic fields don't cause big problems for electronic devices, only hard disks and CRT screens. Your idea sounds possible. But I'm writing this as a comment not an answer because the question "I don't know what I'm doing, is it possible?" isn't really suited for this site.

Comment: @user253751  do you have some reference about it ?if yes ,can you provide it to  me,if no,just tell me no,thankyou

Comment: *..if a signal is transmitted from the ground to this electronic device, ...will the signal be seriously disturbed by the electromagnetic field?* **No** it will not. Signals can generally co-exist without harming each other. The issue is that the receiver of the signal needs to be able to receive the signal without being disturbed by the presence of the HV lines...

Comment: ...Since HV will be 50 or 60 Hz AC and wireless connections are using much higher (RF) frequencies (for example 433 MHz) then there should be **no issue** in making the receiver robust against the 50 / 60 Hz while being able to receive the RF signal  just fine.

Comment: Setting aside the safety issues you should ask the owner of the pylon to see if it's permitted. Also be prepared for some crazy EM field strength